# How many years till photorealistic games?

Tags: raytracing, photo-realistic

I just saw this post by NVIDIA:
[RTX Global Illumination](https://twitter.com/CasualEffects/status/1341818541532655621)

The images shown seem to be rendered in realtime which got me thinking about when games will achieve full photorealism and become indistinguishable from reality (or CGI). Games have only begun to use Ray tracing, and even a fully photorealistic engine may not be purely Ray tracing based but it looks like the way forward. A cursory search could not find any related 'moore's law' of photorealism which i find a bit odd since the simulation part has already been worked out (we've had ray tracing since the beginning of computer graphics) and the programmers seem to be waiting for improvements in hardware.

Ignoring how other aspects of game development like tooling and artistic input, clumsy physics, uncanny valley etc. will cope with high visual fidelity, when, if ever, will we be able to move around and interact in a world that looks just like the real world.

Comment: Closing this question since it can only be answered by speculations or opinions and not by facts. Please read the [help pages](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help) to learn which questions can be asked here. If you really like to discuss this topic I suggest asking this question in a forum like www.gamedev.net